# Как создать матрицу с добавлением элементов в C?

Tags: c

Нужно создать матрицы с добавлением елементов, а также совершить математические операции над ними.

Comment: Вопрос неясен. Массив вида int a[2][2] = {{5, 5}, {10, 10}}; - это и есть матрица. Что именно нужно?

Comment: я имею введу то, что нужно создать матрицу с вводом елементов. Например матрица А 3х4
и нужно вручную вводить эти самые елементы. Делать это нужно через цикл или как? Я понимаю как создать матрицу с помощью массивов, но как вручну задавать елементы не очень(.

Comment: С чем именно проблема? С чтением ввода пользователя?

Comment: Да! Как правильно это реализовать на с?

Comment: @Nychos я дополнил свой ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для решения задачи Вам необходимо сделать ровно то, что Вы нам сообщили.

*P.S. Правду говорят — в вопросе обычно содержится если не весь, то половина ответа =).*

---

Вот набросал элементарнейший пример чтения массива:

```
int N;
printf("Enter number of items: ");
scanf("%d", &N);

int *arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    printf("Enter item #%d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &(arr[i]));
}

// …

free(arr);
```

Обратите внимание, на то, что вариант далёк от идеала, поскольку нет никакой проверки корректности ввода. Но Вам, как я понимаю, надо для учебного задания, так что сойдёт.

Comment: Человек, должно быть, имел в виду, что ему надо какую-то готовую динамическую структуру, которую можно было бы нахаляву увеличивать :)

Comment: Неее. В таких случая обычно так и спрашивают — мол, как сделать, чтобы легко добавлялись элементы.

Comment: Так вот так и спросили: "с добавлением элкментов" :) Хотя, возоможно я всегда вижу сложности там, где их нет :)

Comment: И на этом спасибо! Как говориться: дали пример, а я как-то дальше сам))

Comment: ошибка: ‘new’ не описан (первое использование в этой функции

Тэг установлен в C, а не C++

Comment: Прошу прощения, на автомате написал… Сейчас исправлю свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если приложение консольное, то ввод размерностей и значений элементов делается функцией scanf. Сами матрицы размещаются на стеке (C99 это позволяет). Сложение, вычитание, умножение и другие операции делаются в цикле поэлементно над всеми ячейками матриц.

Можно все сделать самому или взять готовый код из википедии, например: [Умножение матриц](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86).

Comment: Речь не о размещении на стеке (это в C и раньше не возбранялось), а об указании переменной в качестве границы, напр. int arr[N];